# LAN chat software between Linux and Windows

Tags: windows, linux, chat, cross-platform, intranet

I am the only one in our office using Linux, while everything is working great except the team-communication.

I just need to send/receive text message, images, files with my teammates.

I have set up a rocket.chat service on my machine, but after some days using it, I really like this web-based chat service, but it's desktop notify feature does't work. So my teammates can't always response in time.

I am looking a server-less solution, it will be better if such software can scan all users in the same network automatically.

It should support Windows of course.

Any good suggestion?

Comment: @Darius our working network is isolated with the internet..

Answer (score 1):

You could try pidgin with the bonjour protocol, it's not very modern but it should work.

The following article shows how it works: 
http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2011/11/use-pidgin-for-chatting-and.html
(You will need to install the bonjour service)

> Today I'd like to show you how to use Pidgin for chatting and transferring files on local network. You can do this even without Internet connection

Comment: ...or if someone don't like the GUI or a feature of Pidgin, any other client with the bonjour protocol. **;-)**